# How to merge two lists?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists (ObservableCollections) of following class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

One representing old objects (`listA`) and second representing updated ones (`listB`). I want to merge new data from `listB` to `listA` without breaking any references. More precisely I want to do the following:

- Remove from `listA` all objects that do not exist in `listB` (objects are compared by `Key` property)
- Add to `listA` all objects from `listB` that do not exist in `listA`
- Update `Value` property for all objects in `listA` that are present in both lists

Can you propose some efficient way to do that? My solution is big and seems very ineffective.

**Update:**
Current solution is:

```
public void MergeInstanceList(List<Instance> instances)
{
    var dicOld = Instances.ToDictionary(a => a.Ip);
    var dicNew = instances.ToDictionary(a => a.Ip);
    var forUpdate = instances.Intersect(Instances, new Comparer()).ToList();
    Instances.Where(a => !dicNew.Keys.Contains(a.Ip)).ToList().ForEach(a => Instances.Remove(a));
    instances.Where(a => !dicOld.Keys.Contains(a.Ip)).ToList().ForEach(a => Instances.Add(a));
    forUpdate.ForEach(a => dicOld[a.Ip].Name = a.Name);
}
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Instance>
{

    public bool Equals(Instance x, Instance y)
    {
        return x.Ip == y.Ip;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Instance obj)
    {
        return obj.Ip.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your current solution so that we can see how it could be imprved?

Comment: I don't know how big your collections are, but (generally) wouldn't it be easier to rephrase the problem like this: Get all items from listB (current ones) and append items from listA not present in listB (the ones that were not updated). In such case, `var listC = listB.Union(listA);` with custom `IEqualityComparer` should be OK...

Comment: Well my data class is actually more complicated. I will remove some unneeded code and post it in 5 mins. // done.

Comment: The way you've described your question, all you really want in the end is a copy of List B to appear in List A...how come you don't just clear List A and add everything from List B?

Comment: This is probably a stupid comment, but couldn't you just use listB, i.e. assign listB to where currently listA is used?

Comment: @Ryan, FrankE as I said, I don't want to break any references to items that exist in both lists, just update their data.

Comment: @Poma  But, if you do update you just end up with ListB Because the only items that weren't in both lists are only in ListB.

Comment: You show a `Data` class then only use an `Instance` class...  You define that objects will be compared by `Key` then compare by `Ip`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes, the resulting list will be almost the same as listB, except references. For example I may have subscribed to some events in my data class. Or, I display this list in ListBox and want my selection pointer to survive list update.

Comment: @poma you show an example of List<Instance> which is not observable...

Comment: Some style commentary:  don't use var.  Don't use .ForEach().  And especially don't use .ToList().ForEach().  Do use different names for variables with different purposes (not just "a" all the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var listA = ...;
var listB = ...;

var itemsToRemove = new HashSet<Data>(listA.Except(listB));
var itemsToAdd = listB.Except(listA);
var itemsToUpdate = listA.Join(listB, a => listA.Key, b => listB.Key, 
            (a, b) => new
            {
                First = a,
                Second = b
            });

listA.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
listA.RemoveAll(item => itemsToRemove.Contains);
foreach(var pair in itemsToUpdate)
{
  //set properties in First to be that of second
}
```

As is mentioned in another answer, you will need to create a custom comparer and pass it into the two `Except` methods for them to work properly, or you will need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to be based off of just `Key`.

Comment: You are right. Join is better than two OrderBys and a Zip. +1 for Join.

Comment: RemoveRange only accepts integer parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5

Comment: @DavidB Right you are, will convert to a `RemoveAll` call now.

Comment: @Servy RemoveAll does not exist on ObservableCollection.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: The most readable solution. Thank you. I indeed have small data sets. `ObservableCollection` doesn't contain batch adds or deletions though. Will use `List<T>.ForEach`.

Answer (score 1):

With following *EqualityComparer*,

```
public class DataEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Data>
{
    public bool Equals(Data x, Data y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.Key == y.Key;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Data obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

You can find out elements like following:

```
DataEqualityComparer comparer = new DataEqualityComparer();

var InListAButNotInListB = listA.Except(listB, comparer);
var InListBButNotInListA = listB.Except(listA, comparer);

var InListAThatAreAlsoInListB = listA.Intersect(listB, comparer).OrderBy(item => item.Key);
var InListBThatAreAlsoInListA = listB.Intersect(listA, comparer).OrderBy(item => item.Key);

var InBothLists = InListAButNotInListB.Zip(InListBButNotInListA, (fromListA, fromListB) => new { FromListA = fromListA, FromListB = fromListB });
```

Comment: Your inbothlists just gives you the items on one list (listA) not the item in listA and the corresponding item in listB to update.

Comment: @Servy : It says "all objects in listA that are present in both lists"

Comment: The idea is that you have two objects, with different references, but the same `Key`, so they logically represent the same thing.  Their other (non-key) properties are different, and they need to be made to be the same.

Comment: As seen in my answer, `Join` is more appropriate here.  Rather than just doing the work twice, and also doing two sorts and a Zip, just use a tool that give you the results you need in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Key is unique, and that replacing the listA ObservableCollection instance is forbidden...

```
Dictionary<string, Data> aItems = listA.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
Dictionary<string, Data> bItems = listB.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);

foreach(Data a in aItems.Values)
{
  if (!bItems.ContainsKey(a.Key))
  {
    listA.Remove(a); //O(n)  :(
  }
  else
  {
    a.Value = bItems[a.Key].Value;
  }
}

foreach(Data b in bItems.Values)
{
  if (!aItems.ContainsKey(b.Key)
  {
    listA.Add(b);
  }
}
```

The dictionaries give O(1) lookups between the collections, and provide a copy to enumerate over (so we don't get the "can't modify collections that are being enumerated" exception).  This should be O(n) as long as nothing is removed.  The worst case is O(n^2) if everything is removed.

If the listA ObservableCollection instance isn't required to hold the answer, it's better to create a listC instance and add everything that should be there (Remove is so bad).

Comment: Your worst case is O(n*2) not O(n^2), which is still O(n).  Remove is also much less bad when you find all of the items to remove and use 'RemoveRange' (demonstrated in my answer) because rather than moving all of the items that are out of place one at a time, it does all of the moving once at the end.  While the big O is the same, it's quite a bit quicker.

Comment: @Servy Everything in this comment is "worst case".  Assuming that RemoveRange worked as you say, your solution enumerates a and b many times:  a+b + a+b + a+b + b + a + a = 6a + 4b.  If RemoveRange works as the documentation says, then your solution is actually: a^2 + 5a + 4b.  My solution enumerates the collections like this: a + b + a*a + b = a^2 + a + 2b

Comment: generating each of the 3 queries in my answer are each O(a+b), resulting in 3a+3b.  `AddRange` adds b, `RemoveAll` adds another "a", and the foreach adds another a, for 5a+4b.  How do you get from there to a^2+5a+4b?  `RemoveAll` (and RemoveRange) are both O(n) operations, and I only make one call, not n calls.  I agree your evaluation of your own method.

Comment: I miscounted a's. Anyhoo, there's no O(n) option to remove many items from the observable collection, so you're stuck n^2. RemoveAll and RemoveRange do not exist on ObservableCollection.

Comment: It seems so.  That's a shame.  There isn't even a way (that I can see) to use a different backing collection.  At this point the only real thing that my solution has going for it is that it's a bit more readable, and that you separate out each of the 3 distinct operations rather than doing them together (which is of course what makes it slower).  If I knew it was small data sets I'd use my method, if they were large I'd use yours.

Answer (score 0):

System.Linq.Enumerable doesn't have a Full Outer join method, but we can build our own.

```
//eager full outer joiner for in-memory collections.
public class FullOuterJoiner<TLeft, TRight, TKey>
{
  public List<TLeft> LeftOnly {get;set;}
  public List<TRight> RightOnly {get;set;}
  public List<Tuple<TLeft, TRight>> Matches {get;set;}

  public FullOuterJoiner(
    IEnumerable<TLeft> leftSource, IEnumerable<TRight> rightSource,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector, Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector
  )
  {
    LeftOnly = new List<TLeft>();
    RightOnly = new List<TRight>();
    Matches = List<Tuple<TLeft, TRight>>();

    ILookup<TKey, TLeft> leftLookup = leftSource.ToLookup(leftKeySelector);
    ILookup<TKey, TRight> rightLookup = rightSource.ToLookup(rightKeySelector);

    foreach(IGrouping<TKey, TLeft> leftGroup in leftLookup)
    {
      IGrouping<TKey, TRight> rightGroup = rightLookup[leftGroup.Key];
      if (!rightGroup.Any()) //no match, items only in left
      {
        LeftOnly.AddRange(leftGroup);
      }
      else  //matches found, generate tuples
      {
        IEnumerable<Tuple<TLeft, TRight>> matchedTuples =
          from leftItem in leftGroup
          from rightItem in rightGroup
          select Tuple.Create<TLeft, TRight>(leftItem, rightItem);

        Matches.AddRange(matchedTuples);
      }
    }
    foreach(IGrouping<TKey, TRight> rightGroup in rightLookup)
    {
      IGrouping<TKey, TLeft> leftGroup = leftLookup[rightGroup.Key];
      if (!leftGroup.Any()) //no match, items only in right
      {
        RightOnly.AddRange(rightGroup);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For this question, it can be used this way:

```
ObservableCollection<Data> listA = GetListA();
ObservableCollection<Data> listB = GetListB();

FullOuterJoiner<Data, Data, string> joiner =
  new FullOuterJoiner(listA, listB, a => a.Key, b => b.Key);

foreach(Data a in joiner.LeftOnly)
{
  listA.Remove(a);  // O(n), sigh
}
foreach(Data b in joiner.RightOnly)
{
  listA.Add(b);
}
foreach(Tuple<Data, Data> tup in joiner.Matched)
{
  tup.Item1.Value = tup.Item2.Value;
}
```